# Ansible. Unable to ping EC2 instance from Cygwin

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

Trying to run very basic Ansible ping operation from Cygwin against AWS EC2, but without any success.

Have the following configuration in place:

ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
hostfile = hosts
host_key_checking = False
```

hosts:

```
[local]
localhost

[servers]
server-1 ansible_ssh_host=ec2-54-175-139-180.compute-1.amazonaws.com ansible_ssh_user=ec2-user ansible_ssh_private_key_file=ansible.pem
```

All these files + PEM file are located in the same folder.
I'm able to connect to EC2 via SSH using PEM file. I'm also able to telnet. Ping works perfectly.But the following command fails constantly:

**ansible server-1 -m ping -vvv**

with the following error message:

```
   <ec2-54-175-139-180.compute-1.amazonaws.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<ec2-54-175-139-180.compute-1.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -q -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 'IdentityFile="ansible.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ec2-user -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath=/home/UserHome/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r' ec2-54-175-139-180.compute-1.amazonaws.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469264080.61-242019267058306 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1469264080.61-242019267058306="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469264080.61-242019267058306 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
server-1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

What is wrong there? I've seen multiple questions regarding the same issue, but unfortunately no solutions... I'm using 2.1 version of Ansible.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Where are you running the Ansible script from?

Comment: What do you mean? Running it from Cygwin:)

Comment: So are you able to SSH to the instance from Cygwin terminal?

Comment: Yep. This command works just perfectly:

ssh -i pemfile.pem ec2-user@ec2-54-175-139-180.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Comment: In ansible you are using "ansible.pem" and in your SSH you are using "pemfile.pem" is that by mistake or it is correct?

Comment: It's same file in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution.

Adding this to my ansible.cfg solved the issue:

[ssh_connection]

ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no

Answer (score 0):

By default, Ansible 1.3 and later will try to use native OpenSSH for remote communication when possible. This enables ControlPersist (a performance feature), Kerberos, and options in ~/.ssh/config such as Jump Host setup. However, when using Enterprise Linux 6 operating systems as the control machine (Red Hat Enterprise Linux and derivatives such as CentOS), the version of OpenSSH may be too old to support ControlPersist. On these operating systems, Ansible will fallback into using a high-quality Python implementation of OpenSSH called ‘paramiko’. If you wish to use features like Kerberized SSH and more, consider using Fedora, OS X, or Ubuntu as your control machine until a newer version of OpenSSH is available for your platform – or engage ‘accelerated mode’ in Ansible.

Check documentation for Accelerated Mode here http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_acceleration.html

Comment: The doc says:
"In order to use accelerated mode, simply add accelerate: true to your play:"
But I'm not even using a playbook.

Comment: Which version of OpenSSH does Ansible use?

Comment: What is the version of your Ansible